# depends on project with aggregates

Tags: scala, sbt

I moving big project from maven to sbt and have some problems. One of them is next:

I have a project A that depends on projects B-1, B-2, B-3...
(in pom.xml it looks like a lot of dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            B-1
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            B-2
        </dependency>
        ...
</dependencies>
```

)
 I also have a project B that have subprojects B-1, B-2, B-3... (in pom.xml is is looks like

```
<modules>
  <module>B-1</module>
  <module>B-2</module>
  <module>B-3</module>
  ...
</modules>
```

So in my Build.scala I have:

```
lazy val B = (Project("B", file("someFile"))
   aggregate(B-1, B-2, B3, ...))
```

I think in Build.scala I can declare project A like this:

```
lazy val A = (Project("A", file("doesn't matter"))
   dependsOn(B))
```

But this don't works. I don't understand why and how to fix it?
Cause write like:

```
lazy val A = (Project("A", file("doesn't matter"))
   dependsOn(B-1, B-2, B3))
```

is superfluous and ugly.

Comment: Which sbt task are you running and where? Can you post the rest of your build file?

Comment: Sbt task is "> A/compile".
My Build.scala is very large, so I dont want to post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want`A` to depend on `B` which in turn depends on `B-1` and `B-2` (aka `B-1` and `B-2` will be available to `A`) you need to use `dependsOn`:

```scala
lazy val B1 = Project("B1", file("b1"))
lazy val B2 = Project("B2", file("b2"))
lazy val B = Project("B", file("b")).dependsOn(B1, B2)
lazy val A = Project("A", file("a")).dependsOn(B)
```

Note that `aggregate` is different from `dependsOn`:

from the [sbt docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html):

> Aggregation means that running a task on the aggregate project will also run it on the aggregated projects.

You may also want to consider making the dependency explicit from `A` to `B-1` etc, if it may happen that `B` is not needed.

Comment: But project B isn't depends on B1 and B2. Actually it is just a empty project that have a lot of subprojects inside. So there is almost only one <modules> section in it pom.xml.

Comment: Yep, looks like my project B should `aggregate` and `dependsOn` B-1, B2 projects